# Getting the wrong coordinates

Tags: java

The `placedShapeInfo()` gives me almost the correct result except it gives me wrong coordinates for `Shapes at (?,?)` like in the following test case:
[image]

It seems Im doing smth wrong while reading this line in `placedShapeInfo()`:

```
"("+coords.get(i)+"," + coords.get(i+1)+")"
```

Each time a shape passed to `placeShapeAt(int row, int col, Shape shape)` I add its `row` and `col` into the `Arraylist coords`.
Could smb help me out with this?

```
import java.util.*;

public class CreateSpace implements Space{

    private int height;
    private int width;
    //private int placedAtRow = 0;
    //private int placedAtCol = 0;
    private String layout;
    private char[][] space;
    private Shape originalShape;
    private ArrayList<CreateShape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> coords = new ArrayList<>();


    Set<Character> shapesCount;

    public CreateSpace(int height, int width, char[][] space, String layout)
    {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.space = space;
        this.layout = layout;
    }
    public void placeShapeAt(int row, int col, Shape shape)
    {
        int row1 = row;
        int col1 = col;

        int sHeight = shape.getHeight();
        int sWidth = shape.getWidth();

        char [][] spaceWithShapes = space;
        if(shapeFitsAt(row, col, shape))
        {
            for(int r = 0; r < sHeight; r++)
            {
                for(int c = 0; c < sWidth; c++)
                {

                    if(spaceWithShapes[r+row][c+col] == '.' && shape.isFilledAt(r, c))// && shape.isFilledAt(r,c) == true) //|| (((CreateShape)shape).getShape()[r][c] == '.'))
                    {
                        spaceWithShapes[r+row][c+col] = shape.getDisplayChar();
                    }

                }

            }

            shapes.add((CreateShape)shape);
            coords.add((Integer)row1);
            coords.add((Integer)col1);
            //shapes.add((Integer)row1);
            Collections.sort(shapes);
            setSpace(spaceWithShapes);

        }


        else                                                           
            throw new FitItException("The shape does not fit!");
    }
public String placedShapeInfo() 
    {
        Collections.sort(shapes);
        int shapesTotal = placedShapeCount();
        String desc = shapesTotal + " shapes placed";
        String getShapeInfo = "";


        for(int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++)
            //for(int j = 0; j < coords.size(); j++)
        {

            getShapeInfo +="Shape at " + "("+coords.get(i)+"," + coords.get(i+1)+")" + "\n" + shapes.get(i).toString() + "\n";
            System.out.println();
        }

        return desc + "\n" +
             getShapeInfo;
```

Comment: Displaying your entire source may help to find out the error involved.

Comment: @RezwanAzfarHaleem, what source do you mean? The trace of the test case?

Comment: Any other places you may have utilized the ArrayList `coords`.

Comment: @RezwanAzfarHaleem, that's the whole code where I've used ArrayList of `coords`.

Comment: Ok, In that case I have no idea where the problem is :P . Sorry Tho

Answer (score 2):

Your `coords` is a list of integers. So you add two shapes at (1,2) and (3,4). So `coords` is now (1,2,3,4).

Then you iterate through your list of shapes and for each shape get `coords.get(i)` and `coords.get(i+1)`. Are you seeing the problem yet?

For your first shape, i=0 and you get `coords` 0 and 1, which gives you (1,2).

For your second shape, i=1 and you get `coords` 1 and 2, which gives you (2,3).

You're not using `i` consistently. Maybe each shape should know its own coordinates and you should ask it for its x and y instead of storing them in an external data structure. That's one way of dealing with it, and that's the sort of thing OO programming is good at.